# Trouble with combining CSV files

Tags: python, csv

I am combining CSV files for a project and am having trouble getting my second script to work. I used the following code to combine the first set of files, which worked fine:

```
import os
import glob
os.chdir(r"C:\Users\maria\Desktop\Project\TRI\Alabama TRI")
fout=open("out.csv","a")
for line in open("Alabama1988.csv"):
    fout.write("Alabama  "+str("1988")+"  "+line)    
for num in range(1989,2018):
    f = open("Alabama"+str(num)+".csv")
    f.__next__() 
    for line in f:
         fout.write("Alabama  "+str(num)+str("  ")+line)
    f.close()
fout.close()
```

And this is my second, which is not working at all for some reason:

```
import os
import glob
os.chdir(r"C:\Users\maria\Desktop\Project\TRI\CombinedStates")
fout=open("out.csv","a")
for line in open("Alabama.csv"):
    fout.write(line)
statelist = ["Alaska", "Arizona", "Arkansas", "California", "Colorado", "Connecticut", "Delaware", "Florida", "Georgia", "Hawaii", "Idaho", "Illinois", "Indiana", "Iowa", "Kansas", "Kentucky", "Louisiana", "Maine", "Maryland", "Massachusetts", "Michigan", "Minnesota", "Mississippi", "Missouri", "Montana", "Nebraska", "Nevada", "New Hampshire", "New Jersey", "New Mexico", "New York", "North Carolina", "North Dakota", "Ohio", "Oklahoma", "Oregon", "Pennsylvania", "Rhode Island", "South Carolina", "South Dakota", "Tennessee", "Texas", "Utah", "Vermont", "Virginia", "Washington", "West Virginia", "Wisconsin", "Wyoming"]
for state in statelist:
    f = open(str(state)+".csv")
    f.__next__()
    for line in f:
         fout.write(line)
    f.close()
fout.close()
```

I checked to make sure all the spelling and stuff was right both in the code and in the file names, plus I made sure all the files were formatted the same way, but I still have not been able to get it to work. I am wondering if I might be making some error in the second code that is noticeable or if anyone else has any ideas. The code is not returning any error messages and seems to be running when I run it, but the out.csv file is not created. Thanks!

Comment: That is very strange. After you run the script (and finished running, right?) you have no file in `C:\Users\maria\Desktop\Project\TRI\CombinedStates\out.csv`?

Comment: Do you have files named `Alaska.csv`, `Arizona.cvs`, etc in the `C:\Users\maria\Desktop\Project\TRI\CombinedStates` directory when the second script is run? Do they have more than one line in them?

Comment: Right. And yep I finished running it, plus the other code I used worked several times and is almost the exact same, so I am very confused...

Comment: And yes, I do have all those files in the directory with more than one line

Comment: I asked because the first script creates a file named `out.csv` in the `C:\Users\maria\Desktop\Project\TRI\Alabama TRI` directory, which is not the same directory that the second script is reading all the individual state files from — so it does not appear that the two script have anything to do with one another.

Comment: The first script was one I used to combine files in a different directory - the ones for each year of data within each state (specifically Alabama in the code shown). I combined the year files to just get one file per state with all the data. Then I moved those all into a folder called CombinedStates, and I am now trying to combine those (without success). They aren't necessarily related scripts, but they do essentially the same thing except only one of them works.

Answer (score 0):

if the purpose is to combine this 2 csv files and they match exactly, just use pandas

```
import pandas as pd
import os
os.chdir(r"C:\Users\maria\Desktop\Project\TRI\Alabama TRI")

df1 = pd.read_csv('Alabama1988.csv')

os.chdir(r"C:\Users\maria\Desktop\Project\TRI\CombinedStates")

df2 = pd.read_csv('Alabama.csv')

df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2])

os.chdir(r"C:\Users\maria\Desktop")

df3.to_csv('Alambama.csv')
```

Comment: I've tried using pandas, and for some reason it says ```unresolved import 'pandas'``` Do you know why that might be? Thanks!

Comment: Never mind I fixed that error, but it is still not working for some reason.

Comment: @MariaValentini you need to install pandas first. depending on your OS. So it doesn't work and gives no error?

Comment: Yep I installed pandas and got that figured out! But no, it still is not working and gives no error messages.